# Expo Android badge number not showing for notifications

Tags: react-native, expo

Building an application with Expo and React Native.

Quick question:

We have been able to send badge number count via Apple push service, and the IOS App icon shows the badge number correctly.

How is this done with Android? So that when a notification has been sent and is in the tray, it shows either a bubble or the number of notifications that are currently not read.

I cannot find any information regarding this, is this not something Android has on a standard basis?

Thank you for your time!